# I want to find out id of ul li a

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an automation script. I am dealing with ajax drop down.
While click on text box `[input type=text ]` it generates a ul list.
Like this:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-121" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 100002; display: block; top: 26px; left: 0px; width: 392px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-327" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span style="display:inline-block;">Select Org Unit</span></a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-328" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span style="display:inline-block;">10</span></a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-329" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span style="display:inline-block;">1A</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

It always generates a unique id, so I can't use ids for click. Is there any way I can find by text/val and than get id and click on it?

Comment: i was tried this but wasnt work  $(" li a span:contains('adm')").click(function(){
  var id = $('a').attr('id'); });

Answer (score 2):

You can get the respective ID as:

```
$("ul li a").on('click', function(){
      var myID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: There is a big problem here, because the list is dynamically generated

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function(){ // your handler here })` is what you want.

Comment: No problem, the 'on' event handler will take care of it...!! Please check it and let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can compare I am assuming your class name is same for all li tags:

```
$("li.ui-menu-item").each(function(){
   if($(this).children().children().text()==10)
      var id=$(this).children().attr("id");
      $("#"+id).on("click", function () {
          alert("clicked");
      });
});
```

Comment: Hi, so what i actually want is to Check the text and not the id's as the id's are generated dynamically and only text is static. Also i want to first compare the text then Click/select.

Comment: Yes its work thanks very much :) .... but i want click with the id ...could you please help me on this

Comment: What is the functionality of the anchor tag ??you have not mentioned the href attribute in the <a> tag.

Comment: Edited now ..check ... is this what you want ? and if it helps accept the answer..

Comment: thanks very much ... but the previous code works and read the ids correctly but this code cant click on the list item .........the hierarchy is ul-li-a-span than comes text .... here is screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/3b2swvtjnbc73q1/scree-1.png?dl=0

Comment: you have to write href="#" in your anchor tag to work it properly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to obtain, but you can select the node you're looking for based on the text content, using [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). For example:

```
$("ul > li.ui-menu-item > a:contains('1A')").click();
```

That would emit the `click` event on the element on the second menu-item; assuming the text content is unique.

You can also retreive the `id` using:

```
var id = $("ul > li.ui-menu-item > a:contains('1A')").attr('id');
```

And of course adding `click` listeners and so on. Once you have the right selector to address the element(s), you can do everything you need.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately there is nothing similar to `:contains` in regular DOM API, to use with `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`. In JavaScript you need to do extra code in order to have similar functionality, also in term of readability. Using ES6 method like [Array's find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [String's includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) you could write something like:

```
// Array's method cannot be used directly on value from `querySelectorAll`;
// because such method returns a NodeList; so we need a
// generic to use on Array-like object

var find = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.find);

// this function creates a function to use as predicate
// in `find` using the text given

var contains = function(text) {
  return function (element) { return element.textContent.includes(text) }
}

// once you have such functions, you can write:

var a = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li.ui-menu-item > a");

find(a, contains("1A")).click();
```

I didn't use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) only because if your environment doesn't support ES6 yet, you can easily using the shims provided in the documentation, where you can't "shim" the syntax unless you don't use a transpiler (otherwise you could make `contains` more readable with arrow's function).

Comment: can we convert in this query in to javascript .......$("ul > li.ui-menu-item > a:contains('1A')").click(); ..... I cant use in Testcomplete its gave me an error

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do so using simply `querySelector`, 'cause there is nothing like `:contains` at the moment. I will update my answer with some example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation, because you said, the list is loaded via ajax. So, add click listener for `<ul>` element, and filter only the links `<a>` which is a children of `<li>` like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li a', function(){
    console.log('ID:', $(this).attr('id'));
});

// Just a simulation for dynamically loaded elements/links
setTimeout(function() {
    var list = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
       list.push('<li><a href="#" id="ID-' + i + '">Link-' + i + '</a></li>');
    }

    $('ul').html(list.join(''));
}, 2000);
```

see [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/josuci/1/edit?html,js,console,output)